# android edit text focus

Tags: android, search

i have two edit text on the layout and on load the cursor has to be on the second edit text. and how to move the edit text above the keypad on load. Re size property does not work. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use android:enabled=true in your editText. Use RelativeLayout to create your view and try not to give height of the editText directly. If you do so the property android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" in your manifest will work.
If you need an example just let me know.

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/middle"
            android:layout_width="10dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true">
        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText 
              android:layout_above="@id/middle"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        </EditText>

        <EditText
              android:layout_below="@id/middle"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        </EditText>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for the quick help and could you please show me an example please it will be of great help

Answer (score 1):

You can just add your layout in a scrollview, and it will automatically scroll up so the edittext be over the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Use editText2.requestFocus(); to take cursor to 2nd EditText.And the EditText will move up automatically.

Comment: thanks for the quick help will try and let you know the result. thanks again